# Printing Noise Seed of Processing Sketch

Tags: processing, perlin-noise, random-seed

There is a function `noiseSeed(int)` to set the seed for a program, but is there any way to print the seed of a program when it begins?

I am making generative art sketches and it would be more convenient to store just a seed number for a result than an entire image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the default random seed value.

Check out [Processing's source code](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java) (specifically the `random()` and `randomSeed()` functions) to see that Processing uses an instance of the [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to generate random numbers. That class does not have a public way to access its seed value, and even if it did, the `internalRandom` used by Processing isn't accessible to you anyway.

What you can do is create your own seed value and then store that in your own variable. Something like this:

```java
long seed;

void setup(){
  seed = (long)random(1000);
  randomSeed(seed);
  println("Seed value: " + seed);
}
```

How you come up with that seed is up to you. Here I'm generating a random seed between `0` and `1000`, but in real life it can be any `long` value.

You could then also input this from the user in order to have repeatable random behavior based on the input value.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to make sure there wasn't a more elegant way to do this.